# Can't install notarized Java app under MacOS Catalina

Tags: java, macos-catalina, notarize

I have an app written in Java.  I use appbundler to bundle the JVM with the app, and I then use pkgbuild to create a .pkg installer.  This has worked fine until I added notarization and upgraded to Catalina.  Notarization and stapling work just fine.  But the .pkg installer generates an error, "trying to install to system volume".

I have updated to the latest version of appbundler.  It creates an app that embeds jdk1.8.0_151.jdk.

Here's my entitlements.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/    PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I use the following commands to create the installer:

```
$ ant # creates appBundle/Myapp.app
$ codesign -s "Developer ID Application" --timestamp --options runtime -fv --entitlements entitlements.plist --deep appBundle/Myapp.app
$ /usr/bin/ditto -c -k --keepParent appBundle/Myapp.app Myapp.zip
$ xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "com.myapp.tony.Myapp" -u "developer@myapp.com" -p <xxx> --file Myapp.zip
$ xcrun altool --notarization-info <xxx> -u "developer@myapp.com" -p <xxx>
$ xcrun stapler staple appBundle/Myapp.app
$ pkgbuild --root appBundle Myapp.pkg
```

When I double-click Myapp.app in the finder, it runs fine.  If I run Myapp.pkg, the installer runs successfully, but it replaces the copy in my development directory.  To get Myapp installed in the Applications directory, it is necessary to run `sudo pkgutil --forget com.myapp.tony.Myapp`.  Then when I run Myapp.pkg again, after the installer requests my password, it reports, "This package is incompatible with this version of macOS.  The package is trying to install content to the system volume."  This is the same as what is reported to me by users trying to install for the first time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Harded runtime still causes issues with java. I face the same. Try to remove the hardened runtime option (remove: `--options runtime`), it results in warnings for the time being.

PS.: You are stapling another file then within altool. Is that really right?

Comment: I tried removing --options runtime, and that didn't fix it.

The error report I initially got that alerted me to the problem was from a user who was trying to install a package I released two years ago, long before I heard of notarization and hardening.